# Is using a Jquery function executed at server side or client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example the line below
$(“#commentForm”).validate();

after the web page is
initially loaded, does the execution requires further communication with the
server or it is handled at the client’s side?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Javascript and jquery are handled client side, for communication with server ajax is used

Comment: JavaScript can run both on the client and server side, and jQuery is just a JavaScript library. However, it is *mostly* used in client side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is the language works on the client side. And jQuery is kinda an extension of Javascript so the same with jQuery.

If you need to communicate to the server, you can learn about AJAX request :)